# RSSI or Link Quality for BLE connected devices

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, rssi

Is there a way to find out the RSSI or Link Quality of a BLE connection after we perform connect in Linux environment?

hci_read_rssi() from hci_lib.h in Bluez, "hcitool rssi ", "hcitool lq ", and also the vendor specific HCI_VS_Read_RSSI (0xFDFC) command (https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru442b/swru442b.pdf because of the Wl1837MOD chipset that we are using) they all seem to work only on BR/EDR connections and not on LE connections.

Is there a way to find out RSSI or Link Quality or any signal strength from the Bluez APIs for connected BLE devices..?

I am using Bluez V5.48 and hCI/LMP version is Bluetooth 4.2

I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks,

Vinay

Answer (score 0):

It seems like not possible via [DBUS API.](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez/+/refs/tags/5.48/doc/device-api.txt) as it states:

```
int16 RSSI [readonly, optional]
            Received Signal Strength Indicator of the remote
            device (inquiry or advertising).
```

I did not try by myself but you might be able to do this via [Noble.js.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abandonware/noble) `'rssiUpdate'` event listener.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked Noble.js, the "rssiUpdate" event listener doesn't confirm if it works when connected, my assumption is instead of reading RSSI every time the application can register for notifications when RSSI changes but again this could be only applicable during Inquiry or Advert stage. I am working on embedded Linux which has no support to run JS or Node.js. I was looking for a solution in C language.